# Integrating over a region to find probability

Tags: python, integration

I have a joint PDF `p(x,y)`, where `0<x<1, 0<y<1`. I want to find the probability to land in certain region in the parameter space. The parameter space is divided as the following picture:

[image]

The division is governed by a list `flist`. Points where `flist[i][j] = 1` are painted yellow, `flist[i][j]=-1` are painted purple and `flist[i][j]=0` are painted turquoise. The space division is discrete, i.e. there is no function `g(x,y)` that returns `1,-1,0`, but rather the list `flist` was calculated with finite resolution, in a way not relevant to the question.

The list `flist` **was not generated by the probability distribution**. It is an independent thing, used just to get the separation of the parameter space.

Now, given the PDF `p(x,y)`, I want to find the probability to land on the yellow zone. I need to integrate over the yellow zone in order to find this value. The thing is, I don't have a formula for the curve that separates the yellow region from the rest. I am afraid of using heavy machine learning tools, since I am not familiar with them.

Is there a simpler way, using the list `flist`, to integrate over the yellow region?

Comment: why don't you count the number of points of each color dividied by the total number of points? if they are equaly distributed and if you have enough points, you will find a good aproximation of the proba (integrale over total space)

Comment: @Alexis But you have a probability distribution. Your method works if the probability distribution is constant.

Comment: oh yes was thinking about monte carlo but with that it won't work

Comment: I don't understand why. You want a probability to fall into a colored area, how the area was created should not matter?

Comment: @Guimoute the points in `flist` were not generated by `p(x,y)`, but rather they are evenly spaced. Counting how many points are in the yellow and dividing by the total number of points will not take into account the probability distribution.

Comment: So you don't want the relative area of the three segments, but the relative volumnia of the 3 segments in your 2D distribution? Or am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the occurence of each color/number in flist as an indication. I assume flist is a two dimensional list.

```
import numpy as np

farray = np.array(flist)
prob_yellow = (farray==1).sum()/ (farray.shape[0] * farray.shape[1])
prob_purple = (farray==-1).sum()/ (farray.shape[0] * farray.shape[1])
prob_turqoise = (farray==0).sum()/ (farray.shape[0] * farray.shape[1])
```

another way would be to integrate nummerically if you have the x and y arrays of the lines splitting the colored planes. For example:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y_purple = np.exp(-x)
prob_purple = integrate.simps(y_purple,x)
```

---

Edit: I understand now that flist is not evenly distributed. In that case I would first convert it to an evenly distributed list and then use the first method mentioned.

I create the points and flist:

```
points = np.array([[0,0],[0.4, 0.5],[0.5, 0.6],[1, 1]])
flist = np.random.randint(-1,2, size=len(points))
```

Then do the interpolation:

```
import scipy.interpolate as intp
fintp = intp.NearestNDInterpolator(points, flist)

x = np.linspace(0,1,6)
y = np.linspace(0,1,6)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
positions = np.column_stack((xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()))

f_evenly = fintp(positions).reshape(len(x), len(y))
```

and calculate the probability:

```
prob_yellow = (f_evenly==1).sum()/ (f_evenly.shape[0] * f_evenly.shape[1])
prob_turqoise = (f_evenly==0).sum()/ (f_evenly.shape[0] * f_evenly.shape[1])
prob_purple = (f_evenly==-1).sum()/ (f_evenly.shape[0] * f_evenly.shape[1])
```

Check the outcome:

```
plt.imshow(f_evenly, extent=[0,1,0,1])
plt.show()
print('probabilities: \nyellow: %.2f\nturqoise: %.2f\npurple: %.2f'%(prob_yellow,  prob_turqoise, prob_purple))
```

[image: Result]

```
probabilities: 
yellow: 0.47
turqoise: 0.36
purple: 0.17
```

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, it will not work since the list `flist` **was not generated by the probability distribution**. Regarding your second suggestion, well that is the entire question - I don't have this line.

Comment: I added an option for a non evenly distributed flist